# Source Maps/Grunt Plugin for Concatenated CSS files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I am using grunt to simply concatenate and minify my CSS files (not using SASS). Is there something like source maps that I can use? I would like to view the production site and inspect using the Chrome Dev tools but have it tell me the original CSS files. Here is my grunt file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        clean: {
            removeModuleCss: {
                src:["App/**/module.css"]
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            module: {
                files: {
                    'App/styles/module.css': ['App/**/*.css']
                }
            }
        },
        concat: {
            module: {
                src: 'App/styles/**/*.css',
                dest: 'App/styles/module.css'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');

    grunt.registerTask('css', ['clean', 'concat']);
    grunt.registerTask('cssmin', ['clean', 'cssmin']);
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

grunt-contrib-cssmin is not compatible with sourcemaps, yet. I'ts planned for 2.1.

https://github.com/GoalSmashers/clean-css/issues/125

Comment: Thanks for the link, would be very useful if they add it.